# What is a data structure called where a node can assosiate to many other nodes?

Tags: data-structures, terminology

Would is the generic name for a data structure where a node can have many parent and many children, the object itself would be self-referential...

The MySQL tables might look like this:

```
NodeTbl
  id: integer

NodeJoinTbl
  source_node_id: integer
  target_node_id: integer
```

A Persistent Ruby Class might looks like this:

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :nodes
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A graph?.................................

Comment: +1 More specifically a "directed graph" because there is a distinction between source and target

Comment: Yes, and I guess there isn't a difference between a parent and child?